# $\wp$ (unicode U+2118) in title of reference

Tags: bibtex

The symbol $\wp$ or “℘” (unicode U+2118) appears in the title of a reference. My document is using bibtex and I am using Mendeley as a reference manager.  I have two questions:

1. When manually editing the title of the reference to replace ℘ with $\wp$, the command $\wp$ does not display in the bibliography.  How do I get it to display?
2. How can I make Mendeley output the latex command in bibfile?  Typing $\wp$ does not work since Mendeley will output $\backslash$wp.

**Update:**

When using the symbol $\wp$ in general Latex, the symbol still does not display.

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311776/using-ce-and-other-special-characters-in-bib-files-with-pdflatexbiblatexbi

Comment: See also http://danaernst.com/using-mendeley-with-bibtex/.

Comment: Do you load the `amssymb` package?

Comment: Yes I have the amssymb package loaded